# got error can not find openssl while building although I have installed openssl

Tags: cmake, openssl

when I build my program I get this error:I have installed openssl and the error shows me that can not find the appropriate openssl , should I install something else or installing openssl somewhere else?
I am using ubuntu 22.04

```
BUILD_TYPE not set, using debug
RUNNING SCRIPT build

Re-using content of build directory
Passing the following script args to command 
Building debug without unit tests.
-- Running cmake version 3.22.1
-- CMAKE_MODULE_PATH is /home/proj/src/cmake
-- MySQL 8.0.27
-- Source directory /home/proj/src/
-- Binary directory /home/proj/src/build-debug
-- CMAKE_GENERATOR: Ninja
-- SIZEOF_VOIDP 8
-- Packaging as: mysql-8.0.27-Linux-x86_64
-- Found /usr/local/include/boost/version.hpp 
-- BOOST_VERSION_NUMBER is #define BOOST_VERSION 107300
-- BOOST_INCLUDE_DIR /usr/local/include
-- NUMA library missing or required version not available
-- ZLIB_VERSION (bundled) is 1.2.11
-- ZSTD_LEGACY_SUPPORT not defined!
-- ZSTD_VERSION (bundled) is 1.5.0
-- OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR = /usr/include
-- OPENSSL_LIBRARY = /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so
-- CRYPTO_LIBRARY = /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so
-- OPENSSL_MAJOR_VERSION = 
-- OPENSSL_MINOR_VERSION = 
-- OPENSSL_FIX_VERSION = 
-- Looking for SHA512_DIGEST_LENGTH
-- Looking for SHA512_DIGEST_LENGTH - found
-- 
 Cannot find appropriate system libraries for WITH_SSL=system.
 Make sure you have specified a supported SSL version. 
 Valid options are : 
 system (use the OS openssl library), 
 yes (synonym for system), 
 </path/to/custom/openssl/installation>

 CMake Error at cmake/ssl.cmake:61 (MESSAGE):
 Please install the appropriate openssl developer package.

Call Stack (most recent call first):
 cmake/ssl.cmake:319 (FATAL_SSL_NOT_FOUND_ERROR)
 CMakeLists.txt:1613 (MYSQL_CHECK_SSL)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

while I have installed openssl before in usr/include as when I run the command whereis openssl it shows me that it has installed before.

```
whereis openssl
openssl: /usr/include/openssl /usr/share/man/man1/openssl.1ssl.gz
```

Comment: The output is emitted not by CMake itself, but by the project which you are building. The output resembles the one produced by MySQL, do you actually build MySQL? In that case, before the error message you show **other messages** about openssl should be printed. Show these messages (add them to the question post): they should help in understanding why MySQL treats your OpenSSL installation as not supported.

Comment: @Tsyvarev I updated question Thanks please guide me in this

Comment: `-- OPENSSL_MAJOR_VERSION = ` means that MySQL failed to determine the version of your OpenSSL installation. Ubuntu 22.04 is shipped with OpenSSL 3.0 but the MySQL sources you are building aren't prepared for such new OpenSSL. Try to take newer MySQL sources. E.g. from [here](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-server/tree/8.0/cmake).

Comment: it has been fixed here [diff](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-server/commit/a0132f53d93eefe4338a27ce4e3f5ffcc7126596) in branch MySQL 8.0 for openssl 3.x